# xslt apply template and match

Tags: xml, xslt

this is not my code. but it similer to what i want thats why i am using it here. i got this from [here](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/919/)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="event/details">
<xsl:with-param name="title" select="event/title"/> <!-- pass param "title" to matching templates -->
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="details">
<xsl:param name="title"/> <!-- this template takes parameter "title" -->
Title: <xsl:value-of select="$title"/><br/>
Timestamp: <xsl:value-of select="java:DateUtil.getDate(number(timestamp))"/><br/>
Description: <xsl:value-of select="description"/><br/>
</xsl:template>
```

My issue is can i have above match template "details" with parameter and one without parameter? sorry for my english..let me know if i dont make sense i will try my best to reword this. thank you in advanced.

EDIT : here is what i want.

```
template 1 - with parameter:

<xsl:template match="details">
<xsl:param name="title"/> <!-- this template takes parameter "title" -->
Title: <xsl:value-of select="$title"/><br/>
Timestamp: <xsl:value-of select="java:DateUtil.getDate(number(timestamp))"/><br/>
Description: <xsl:value-of select="description"/><br/>
</xsl:template>

template 2 - without parameter:

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="event/details"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="details">
Timestamp: <xsl:value-of select="java:DateUtil.getDate(number(timestamp))"/><br/>
Description: <xsl:value-of select="description"/><br/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you mean.  You should edit your post to include sample input XML and desired output as well.

Comment: I hope this will make sense.. sorry i am new to xslt. basically what i want in c# language is function with parameter and without parameter. so i can use both when i have parameter and when i dont..

Comment: There is no dynamic selection of identically templates (overloading) based on the number and/or type of parameters in XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. It is a recoverable error to have two templates with the same match pattern -- in the best cases only one of these will be selected for execution**.

In your specific example, you can use just the template with the parameter and slightly modify its code so that when the parameter has no value (the empty string), then no title is written.

**Here is a small demonstration how this can be done**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="event/details"/>
        ===========
        <xsl:apply-templates select="event/details">
          <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'Title Provided'"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="details">
        <xsl:param name="title"/>

    <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat(substring('Title: ',
                      1 + 7*not(string-length($title) > 0)
                      ),
            $title)
    "/>
        <br/> Timestamp: 
        <xsl:value-of select="'someTimeStamp'"/>
        <br/> Description: 
        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**In this transformation the template matching `details` is invoked twice -- the first time without a parameter and the second time with a `$title` parameter. In both cases the template produces the wanted output**:

```
<br/> Timestamp: 
        someTimeStamp<br/> Description: 
        <br/>
        ===========
        Title: Title Provided<br/> Timestamp: 
        someTimeStamp<br/> Description: 
        <br/>
```

---

**II. `xsl:function` in XSLT 2.0**

What you want can be achieved with `xsl:function` -- functions written in XSLT -- this feature is available only in XSLT 2.0 (and up). It is perfectly possible to write different overloads of the same function and we have many examples of this.

Comment: thank you for your reply.. but in my case i am trying to modify existing xslt file which is being used by other processes. and i m trying to add parameter to one of many processes to output little bit different. i was trying to avoid to modifying other processes. so i guess i will have to re-write this method with some other way..since i can't override this.. Thank you again.

Comment: @AJP: Templates can be overriden if they belong to different *imported* stylesheets. Please, read about `xsl:import`. Or, if you have XSLT 2.0 processor, just use `xsl:function`, which, as the update to my answer explains, can have different overloads.

Comment: Thank you.. I think i will write new template since my requirment is little different. But i did gain a knowledge from this.. really appricite your time and help.

Comment: @AJP: You are welcome. I didn't mention yet another possibility -- you can output the title in the calling template, before issuing `<xsl:apply-templates select="event/details"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Your two templates differ essentially by saying "if a title has been supplied then display it". To achieve this, you can make the parameter default to an empty sequence (in XSLT 2.0, add `select="()"` to the xsl:param, or in 1.0, `select="/.."`), and adding conditional logic to the template of the form "if $title exists then display it".